# Custom loss function in Keras with TensorFlow Backend for images

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am new to neural networks and keras and am having trouble writing this custom loss function:

[image: loss function]

I am using TensorFlow as backend. I saw other examples and wrote the loss function in this way:

```
from keras import backend as K
def depth_loss_func(pred_depth,actual_depth):
    n = pred_depth.shape[0]
    di = K.log(pred_depth)-K.log(actual_depth)
    di_sq = K.square(di)
    sum_d = K.sum(di)
    sum_d_sq = K.sum(di_sq)
    loss = ((1/n)*sum_d_sq)-((1/(n*n))*sum_d*sum_d) # getting an error in this step
    return loss
```

The error I am getting is :
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'Dimension'`

Also I am not sure how to incorporate the learning rate in the loss function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't you mix `pred_depth` and `actual_depth` with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using "n", which seems not to be the most elegant way in my opinion, try using the `K.mean` function:

```
di = K.log(pred_depth)-K.log(actual_depth)

di_mean = K.mean(di)
sq_mean = K.mean(K.square(di))

loss = (sq_mean - (lamb*di_mean*di_mean)) # getting an error in this step
```

Answer (score 2):

The shape of the tensor is unknown until you feed your loss function with an input during the graph execution. In order to calculate the shape at execution time dynamically you can use `K.shape()`.

Change the first line for:

```
n = K.shape(pred_depth)[0]
```

Regarding the learning rate, just pass it as another parameter. If it is dynamic you can access it through `model.optimizer.lr.get_value()`.